# How to keep a list of lists sorted as it is created

Tags: python, data-structures, multidimensional-array, sorting

I'm reading in a file and pulling in data that includes some strings and some numbers, in Python.  I'm storing this information as lists of lists, like this:

```
dataList = [

['blah', 2, 3, 4],

['blahs', 6, 7, 8],

['blaher', 10, 11, 12],

]
```

I want to keep dataList sorted by the second element of the sub list: dataList[][1]

I thought I could use insort or bisect right when I want to add them in, but I cannot figure out how to make it look at the second element of the sub list.

Any thoughts here?  I was just appending data to the end and then doing a linear sort to find things back later on.  But, throw a few 10's of thousands of sub-lists in here and then search for 100k items and it takes a while.

Comment: Why can't you just add everything and then sort the result?  It seems to me that sorting as you go would be less efficient ...

Comment: I had considered that but had assumed that it would be more efficient to keep it sorted as the items were added.  Maybe not?

Comment: @ErikS insertion in the middle of a python list is [O(n)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: If you really want it to stay sorted as you create it, check out http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577197-sortedcollection/

Comment: What you are describing is equivalent to [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), which runs in *O(n^2)* time. Most good sorting algorithms (like [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) or [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/quicksort)) run in *O(n log n)* time. Thus, it's not more efficient to keep it sorted as you go.

Comment: Note that `bisect.insort_*` is way faster if you want to maintain a large sorted list of something and output the sorted values often.  E.g. a service keeping a global sorted list of message timestamps. (`lst.append(i); return sorted(lst)` vs `bisect.insort_left(lst, i); return lst`). It may not be more efficient to keep the list sorted in this example, but there are definitely cases where it's much faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
dataList.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

*This sorts the list in place, by the second element in each item.*

As has been pointed out in the comments, it is much more efficient to sort just once (at the end). Python's built-in sort method has been **heavily optimised to work fast**. After testing it looks like the built-in sort is consistently around 3.7 times faster than using the [heap method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12324545/1240268) suggested in the other answer, over various size lists (I tested sizes of up to 600000).

Comment: This does not address OP's question about keeping sorted while creating the list.

Comment: Right, I'd run across this.  Is doing a sort after all data is in going to be more efficient than keeping a sorted list?

Comment: @ErikS: yes, this is probably more efficient. It's got the same time-complexity as the heap-insert-then-pop answer, but the coefficients and constant terms are likely to be significantly smaller. If you're really concerned about performance though, I'd test it!

Comment: @ErikS A quick experiment (on 1000 lists of length 10000) suggest that the heap method is 3.5 times slower that Pythons purpose built sort.

Answer (score 8):

Depends on a few things, but the first thing that comes to mind is using the heapq module:

```
import heapq
heap = []
for row in rows:
    heapq.heappush(heap, (row[1], row))
```

This would create a heap full of tuples, where the first element is the element you want to sort by, and the second element is the row.

The simplest method to read them back from the heap would be to copy it then pop items:

```
new_heap = list(heap)
while new_heap:
    _, row = heapq.heappop(new_heap)
    print row
```

The runtime of inserting each item into the heap is `O(lg N)`, so creating the heap will require `O(N lg N)` time, and popping items from the heap also requires `O(lg N)` time, so `O(N lg N)` time will be required to traverse it.

If these tradeoffs are not ideal, you could use a binary search tree (none exist in the standard library, but [they are easy to find](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/1.0.0)), or as other commenters have suggested, sort the rows after reading them: `rows.sort(key=lambda row: row[1])`.

Now, in practice, unless you're dealing with a very large number of rows, it will almost certainly be faster to sort the list in-place after loading it (ie, using the `.sort()` method)… So try a few things out and see what works best.

Finally, `bisect` is a poor idea, because inserting into Python lists requires `O(N)` time, so inserting items with bisect would require `O(N lg N)` time *per item*, so a total time of `O((N lg N) * N) = O(N**2)` time.

Comment: In practice (in Python) I doubt this is faster than creating the list and then sorting it, though it is worth testing.

Comment: @DavidRobinson It isn't faster, it's substantially slower. Python's sort has been optimised heavily!